# How can I make looping background elements?

Tags: html, css

I was learning React when I heard about styled-components.  I went to their website ([styled-components.com](https://styled-components.com/)), and saw an interesting effect.  In the **USED BY FOLKS AT** section, there are two rows of logos which scroll off the screen and come back on the other side.  I tried something in a jsFiddle, but it came out so broken that I just closed it and gave up.

I assume I need to use keyframe animations including `transform: translateX([something])`, but I can't figure out how to make it loop smoothly.  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this helpful?

```css
body {
  -webkit-box-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  background: #e3e3e3;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}

@-webkit-keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
            transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(calc(-250px * 7));
            transform: translateX(calc(-250px * 7));
  }
}

@keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
            transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(calc(-250px * 7));
            transform: translateX(calc(-250px * 7));
  }
}
.slider {
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 960px;
}
.slider::before, .slider::after {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(white), to(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)));
  background: linear-gradient(to right, white 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  content: "";
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.slider::after {
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(180deg);
          transform: rotateZ(180deg);
}
.slider::before {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.slider .slide-track {
  -webkit-animation: scroll 40s linear infinite;
          animation: scroll 40s linear infinite;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  width: calc(250px * 14);
}
.slider .slide {
  height: 100px;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
    <div class="slide-track">
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/1.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/2.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/3.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/4.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/5.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/6.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/7.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/1.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/2.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/3.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/4.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/5.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/6.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/557257/7.png" height="100" width="250" alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the cleanest solution but it does the job (with boxes being any width):

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}

@keyframes myAnimation {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
@keyframes myAnimation2 {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

.row {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  overflow: visible;
  vertical-align: top;

}
.row1 {
  animation: 5s linear 0s infinite normal none running myAnimation;
}
.row2 {
  animation: 5s linear 0s infinite normal none running myAnimation2;
  margin-top: -20px;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: auto;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="row row1">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="row row2">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
<div>
```